# Show the beginning of scrollable panel, when starting program

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I have program that is some kind of testing. I keep questions in panel, but when I run my program, it show the middle of panel. How to make it show the beginning of the panel?
[image]

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Dictionary<string, bool> answers = new Dictionary<string,bool>();
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                {
                    string ans = "Відповідь " + (j+1);
                    bool flag = false;
                    if( i > 5)
                    {
                        if( j == 0 || j == 2)
                        {
                            flag = true;
                        }
                    }else
                        if (j == 0)
                        {
                            flag = true;
                        }
                    answers.Add(ans, flag);
                }
                string q_text = "Питання № " + (i+1);
                this.AddQuestion(q_text, answers);
            }
            panel1.ScrollControlIntoView(panel1.Controls[0]);
        }
```

Comment: Try to give `focus` on 1st `control` in `panel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set focus on the first control in the panel on Form_Load event:

```
panel1.Controls[0].Select();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

1. The [`ScrollControlIntoView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.scrollcontrolintoview.aspx) method:

   ```
   panel.ScrollControlIntoView(panel.Controls[0]);
   ```
2. Panel's [`VerticalScroll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.verticalscroll%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property:

   ```
   panel.VerticalScroll.Value = 0;
   ```

Comment: neither method is not helpful. I write it in Form1_Load, but it still shows the middle of panel

Comment: Try to move this code to the `Form_Shown` event handler. Or show your form's startup code.

Comment: See code above, and I can't find such event handler as Form_Shown

Comment: Make sure that the panel's `AutoScroll` property is `false`. Your code seems to be useless until it doesn't contain `panel1`'s initialization code. You can find the `Shown` event in the designer. :)